# mailmerge: What does 'ValueError: Element is not a child of this node' mean?

Tags: python, docx-mailmerge

I'm trying to populate a Word document in Python with [docx-mailmerge](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/docx-mailmerge/0.3.0). Everything was working fine, but after some editing at home on another computer with another version of Word, my script gives an error at the line:

```
document = MailMerge(template)
```

Error:

```
document = MailMerge(template)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mailmerge.py", line 79, in __init__
parent.remove(child)
File "src\lxml\lxml.etree.pyx", line 950, in lxml.etree._Element.remove 
(src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:50327)
ValueError: Element is not a child of this node.
```

What does this mean?

Comment: what is template ?

Comment: A Word file (*.docx)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't give us any run-time context, but this message simply informs you that the object `lmxl.etree` at the given line, has no attribute (data field) called `Element`.  `etree` apparently exists, but it obviously is not of the expected type or structure.  It's possible that the tree node isn't fully-formed somehow: a spreadsheet cell is empty, or has a seriously invalid value.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with docx-mailmerge. It turned out that in my .docx file curly brackets on a single mergefield were not at the same row, so mailmerge could not detect the merge field properly.

Example: `{ MERGEFIELD Foo                                                                   }`

Fixed: `{ MERGEFIELD Foo }`